# Why does echo on functions.php not yield result in source code?

Tags: functions, theme-development, open-graph

I follow the tutorial in [How to Add Facebook Open Graph Meta Data in WordPress Themes](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-in-wordpress-themes/) and add some `echo` code in `functions.php` both in the main theme and child theme. However, when I check the source code of an individual page, the tags don't show up. Why is that?

The script is below:

```
//Adding the Open Graph in the Language Attributes
function add_opengraph_doctype( $output ) {
        return $output . ' xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
    }
add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');

//Lets add Open Graph Meta Info

function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
        return;
        echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="Ooker"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="Quả cầu"/>';
    if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
        $default_image="http://example.com/image.jpg"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    else{
        $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
    }
    echo "
";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

Comment: Does your theme use `wp_head` in header file?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż there is a line `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the head section of header.php, so yes

Comment: If you set `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` and `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` in wp-config.php do you see any errors or notices in `wp-content\debug.log`?